# jquery multi-dimensional object to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have created a AJAX site where I am getting the response in a multi-dimensional json array, I was getting along quite well but I am having a problem with the ordering of some elements, I have discovered orders are not guaranteed with objects so I have attempted to convert this to an array to sort in Jquery a sample of the json below

```
"lib":{"239":{"stitle":"Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.","title":"Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.","img":"image2.jpg"},"203":{"stitle":"Alexei Sayle's Stuff","title":"Alexei Sayle's Stuff","img":"image2.jpg"},"92":{"stitle":"Anatomy for Beginners","title":"Anatomy for Beginners","img":"image3.jpg"},"180":{"stitle":"Angry Birds","title":"Angry Birds","img":"image4.jpg"}}}
```

I have attempted to convert the objects into an array but it seems only to put the objects inside an array so still have a problem ordering the array, Below is what I have working but seems to be ordering by index rather than order presented from the json.

```
$.each(data.lib, function(index, value){    
        $('.medlst').append('<li class="sersel" id="'lnk_'+index+'"><img src="'+ value.img +'" alt="'+ value.stitle +'" title="'+ value.title +'" height="130px" width="90"></li>');
});
```

I attempted to use $.parseJSON() but this converts json to objects which i already have

if anyone has knowledge of how to convert an object and all child objects into a nested array that will honor the order the json was received I would be much appreciated

Comment: Your code is appending to the DOM, not putting anything into an array.

Comment: Why are you returning an object if the order matters? Return a JSON array.

Comment: Unless you want to write your own JSON parser, there's no easy way to convert the JSON object to an array that preserves the original order. Don't use objects when the order matters.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string provided is invalid as is so a with a slightly modified version, you could do something like the below.

```js
const str = '{"lib":{"239":{"stitle":"Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.","title":"Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.","img":"image2.jpg"},"203":{"stitle":"Alexei Sayle\'s Stuff","title":"Alexei Sayle\'s Stuff","img":"image2.jpg"},"92":{"stitle":"Anatomy for Beginners","title":"Anatomy for Beginners","img":"image3.jpg"},"180":{"stitle":"Angry Birds","title":"Angry Birds","img":"image4.jpg"}}}';

let libs = JSON.parse(str);

// Create an array and populate with
// libs object from JSON, adding
// key into each
var sortedLibs = []; 
for(let key in libs.lib) {
  libs.lib[key].key = parseInt(key); 
  sortedLibs.push(libs.lib[key]);
}

// Sort libs based on key, ascending
sortedLibs.sort((a, b) => a.key > b.key);
console.log(sortedLibs);

// Sort libs based on key, descending
sortedLibs.sort((a, b) => a.key < b.key);
console.log(sortedLibs);
```

Comment: Your sort comparator functions are invalid. You can't just return a boolean that lumps the equal case in with either greater than or less than; this results in undefined behavior. You have to distinguish all three cases: less than, equal, and greater than, and return any negative number, zero, or any positive number for the three. In this code, since the keys can be coerced to numbers, you can do that with subtraction. The first one can be `(a,b) => a.key - b.key` and the second `(a,b) => b.key - a.key`.

Comment: If the sort keys were not numeric (or numbers as strings as in this JSON data), you would have to do two comparisons, either with `if` / `else if` / `else` or two ternary operators: `(a,b) => a.key > b.key ? 1 : a.key < b.key ? -1 : 0` or switched around for descending order. Note that the specific values 1 and -1 are not required. Any positive/negative numbers will work, which is why subtraction works for numeric values - and if the values are strings like these, subtraction converts them to numbers. Zero of course has to be zero.